# gnuplot xlabels alphanumeric and stretching x axis range

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have plotted a file containing string and numbers as x labels with following code

```
plot "fileaskinf.dat" u 2:xticlabels(1) t "teams"
```

The file contents are

```
A-Team  0.05    
0.5 0.03    
0.6 0.05  
0.7 0.07   
S-team  0.05
```

How can I produce offset at the extreme of plots to see where the label "A-team" and "S-team" value resides at y axis. I am also getting vertical line. I don't know why.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you supply categorical data (i.e. `xticlabels`), the tics are separated by 1 unit and start from 0. If you know the number of categories you can therefore hard-code an adjustment using `xrange`. More generally, you can calculate an adjustment based on the `GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN` and `GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX` values, ex. :

```
plot "fileaskinf.dat" u 2:xticlabels(1) t "teams"
set xrange[GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN-0.5:GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX+0.5]
replot
```

See also [gnuplot: max and min values in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13583689/4440445)

---

I don't know what is causing the vertical line in your plot - I cannot reproduce it in Gnuplot 5.2 with the default `wxt` terminal.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Do you know how i can plot same file with yerrorbars from third column (not shown in file). I tried plot "fileaskinf.dat" u 2:xticlabels(1):3 w yerrorbars but i get last  column value in the x axis, which is wrong